# If $f\in\mathcal{H}(\mathbb{C})$ not constant, then $f(\mathbb{C})$ is dense in $\mathbb{C}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

By reductio ad absurdum suppose that $f(\mathbb{C})$ is not dense in $\mathbb{C}$, then there exists $w_0\in\mathbb{C}$ and $\varepsilon_0>0$ such that $|f(\zeta)-w_0|\geq \varepsilon_0$ for all $\zeta\in\mathbb{C}$; this implies:
$$|\frac{1}{f-w_0}|\leq \frac{1}{\varepsilon_0} \text{ for all } \zeta\in \mathbb{C}$$ As $f\in\mathcal{H}(\mathbb{C})$ we have that:
$$\frac{1}{f-w_0}\in\mathcal{H}(\mathbb{C})$$
So by Liouville's theorem $f$ is constant.

Comment: Or you can use the sledgehammer of the little Picard’s theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem)

Comment: It's probably supposed to be $\leq \frac1{\varepsilon_0}$.

Comment: The proof is correct, but in "As $f \in \mathcal H (\mathbb C )$ is not constant" the statement that $f$ is not constant is not needed. (And also Arthur's remark about $\frac{1}{\epsilon_0})$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As $f \in\mathcal{H}(\mathbb{C})$ is not constant we have that: 
>   $$
>  \frac{1}{f-w_0}\in\mathcal{H}(\mathbb{C}).
> $$

I don’t think this is the argument you want to make, as this has nothing to do with $f$ being constant: Instead you have $|f(\zeta) - w_0| \geq \varepsilon_0 > 0$ for all $\zeta \in \mathbb{C}$, so $f - w_0$ has no zeroes; because $f - w_0$ is holomorphic you get that $1/(f-w_0) \in \mathcal{H}(\mathbb{C})$.

Also notice that
$$
 \left| \frac{1}{f(\zeta)-w_0} \right| \leq \frac{1}{\varepsilon_0}
 \quad\text{for all $\zeta \in \mathbb{C}$}.
$$

Aside from this your proof seems correct.